# Judgement calls in applying basic HTML5 elements

Tags: html5

Having developed a page in HTML4 I'm looking to improve my page by developing it in HTML5 and specifically looking to use the header, nav, section, article, aside and footer elments.

I realise its a judgement call to apply the above elements and I've applied some of these HTML element plus I look forward to using more of them but was wondering if my application of these elements so far is ideal or not?

Here's the body section of my code:

```html
    <body>
    <nav required id="topbar"> 
        <a  required id="logo_link" href="">LOGO TEXT ....</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>LOG IN</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Welcome message -->
    <div class="welcome_message">Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... </div>

    <!-- Header Carousel -->
    <header required id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h2>Caption A</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h2>Caption B</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h2>Caption C</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls 
        <div class="arrows"> 
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next"></span>
            </a>
        </div> -->      
    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <section required id="page_content" class="page_content_div">

        <div class="page_content_heading_div" >
            <p> Log in with: </p>
        </div>

        <div class="page_content_main_div">
            <div class="social_sign_in_div">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-facebook large" href="#">Log in with <b>Facebook</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="social_sign_in_div">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-google large" href="#">Log in with <b>Google</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="btn_log_in_with_email_div">
                <a class="btn-auth btn_log_in_with_email large" href="#">Log in with <b>E-mail</b></a>
            </div>

            <hr class="hr"></hr>

            <div class="page_content_heading_div">
                <p>Sign up:</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form_input_div">
                <div class="form_input_internal_div">

                    <input title="Enter first name" class="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" required id="firstname" placeholder="Enter first name">
                </div>

                <div class="form_input_internal_div">
                    <input title="Enter second name" class="secondname" name="secondname" type="text" required id="secondname" placeholder="Enter second name">
                </div>

                <div class="form_input_internal_div">
                    <input title="Type your e-mail" class="email" name="email" type="email" required id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>

                <div class="form_input_internal_div">
                    <input title="Enter a password" class="password" name="password" type="password" required id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>

                <div class="form_input_internal_div">
                    <input title="Re-enter the password" class="reenterpassword" name="reenterpassword" type="password" required id="reenterpassword" placeholder="Re-enter password">
                </div>

                <div class="form_button_internal_div">
                    <button title="Type your second name" type="submit" class="btn_sign_up" id="submit">Sign Up</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form_terms_of_service_internal_div">
                    <p class="terms_of_service">By signing up, I agree to the following <a href='#' id="generic_link_decoration"><b>Terms of Service</b></a> and <a href='#' id="generic_link_decoration"><b>Privacy Policy</b></a>.</p>
                </div>                                

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>      

    <!-- Footer 
    <div class="footer_div">
        <u
            <li><a href='#'>FOOTER MENU OPTION A</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FOOTER MENU OPTION B</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FOOTER MENU OPTION C</aform_input_internal_div></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FOOTER MENU OPTION D</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </div> -->

    <nav class="footer_div"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>TERMS OF SERVICE</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>HELP</a></li>
        </ul>     
    </nav>    

</body>
```

Comment: See [What you may and may not do after receiving answers.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that struck me is your use of `required`. The `required` attribute is [meant for **forms only**](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html), specifically input fields.

Next up: styling. You may not have done styling yet, but in any case I would suggest that you remove your inline styles to an external CSS file and reference it in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
```

Inline styles should be used to change preset styles (such as those set in an external CSS document) for a single use. For example, say you have a pre-defined message box in your CSS file, but you want it to look slightly different for one point on one page only. That should be done inline:

```css
.message {
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 80%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
    background: #AD2622;
 color: white;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="message">This is a normal error message.</span><br/>
<span class="message" style="border-left: 5px solid #8D0602; font-weight: bold;">This is a message with extra styles for emphasis.</span>
```

Otherwise, your use of the HTML5 elements seems sound: you have appropriately used `<section>`, `<nav>`, and `<header>`. What I will say is, since some people **still** insist on IE6 with no HTML5, you may want to include a standard [HTML5 display-reset CSS file](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/).

Comment: really appreciate for the very detailed review of my code.

Comment: Regarding the HTML5 display-reset CSS file is the option you proposed better than what I have which is normalize.css i.e. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: @TokTok123 What you have is better, go with that - although it's not impossible to include both (though it's not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

Consider running your code against [an html validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Doing so revealed the following errors and warnings:

- element `<head>` is missing.
- `required` attribute is invalid
- url encoding issues
- malformed `hr` tag
- duplicate ids
- `section`s should be introduced with `h2`-`h6` elements

Comment: Thanks ... I'll have a look at running my code thru a validator ..